# Xcode compile error on Release Build on a project that uses some framework reference

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8

I am working on a Swift project that uses some frameworks references. It works well when the debug compile. But, When I compile Release it throwing some reference errors like below;

[image]

That failed classes are in the CryptoSwift.framework library and MyFramework using this library. CryptoSwift.framework existing on build phases.

I tried `"Optimization Level -> None [-Onone]"`  but failed.

Swift Version: 2.3, 
Xcode Version: 8.0

Comment: Is that class defined in a source file that it's somehow not included in the `Release` build phase?

Comment: We need more information? Show the complete error. Is `ClassName` part of a framework?

Comment: You probably have a bridging header or class that isn't being compiled with the release build, but is on a debug build.  Check your target dependencies.

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti That classes existing on build phases, I added more information

Comment: I think you have a kind of mismatch between the `CryptoSwift` swift version and yours

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti,  thanks for your answer but swift version is same for debug and release, it working with debug compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked after I selected "Build Active Architecture Only" for Release Compile.
The reason for the error is that the frameworks do not support all architectures.